# How do you delete C:\Program Files\SomeApp without administrator privileges?

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-10

I am currently attempting to delete the C:\Program Files\SomeApp folder on a test PC where I do not know the administrator password. I have access to cmd.exe, powershell, and not much else.

When I try running `rm "C:\Program Files\TestApp\*"` I get this:

```
Confirm
The item at C:\Program Files\TestApp has children and the Recurse parameter was not specified. If you continue, all children will be removed with the item. Are you
 sure you want to continue?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

When I say `y` + `[ENTER]` it says this:

```
At line:1 char:1
+ rm "C:\Program Files\TestApp\*"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (SomeFile.txt:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
rm : Cannot remove item C:\Program Files\TestApp\SomeFile.txt: Access to the path 'SomeFile.txt' is denied.
```

Which was expected, but I was hoping otherwise.

Anyway, Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't unless you bootup from a live CD or something else other than Windows

Comment: WOW! Didn't think of this, ill try it out lol!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **User Account Control** enabled (the default and recommended setting), administrator rights are required to modify the `C:\Program Files` folder.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/user-account-control-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/user-account-control-for-game-developers

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/bb530410(v=msdn.10)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc709691(v=ws.10)